# Как правильно передать доступ сайта на opencart прогеру?

Tags: opencart, ocstore

Столкнулся с таким вопросом: имеется сайт которым занимаюсь по сео, у заказчика нет прогера который мог бы заниматься исправлением ошибок, поэтому это дело поручили мне, найти, заплатить и принять работу. Естественно планирую искать на фриланс биржах. Вопрос заключается в следующем, как передать доступ к сайту, но так чтобы его не сломали и не угнали? Спасибо всем, кто поможет разобраться. (сайт сделан на ocstore)

[image: Первый срин]

[image: Второй скрин]

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ: перед работами сделай бэкап и отдельные доступы на ftp и MySQL, а также в админку. После принятия работы просто удалишь все созданные ранее доступы.

Comment: Спасибо, будем пробовать)

Comment: Главное перед любыми работами это BackUP!

Comment: Я могу скинуть вам перечень прав, а вы посмотрите какие нужно оставлять а какие убрать?

Comment: я добавил сюда скрины с возможными разрешениями к доступу

Comment: Какой хостинг? Не вижу скрина.

Comment: Прикрепил картинку к вопросу. Хост: ukrline